# Parsing List<T> for all values

Tags: c#, list, parsing, generics

I have many classes that are stored in lists. I'm attempting to create a method that accepts a List as a generic type and returns the contents of every element within in the appropriate list as a string.

This is a sample of one of many classes. This would be defined as List<Player>:

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteThing { get; set; }
}
```

I'm still struggling to get the syntax correct here:

```
  public static string GetStringOfData<T>(List<T> data)
    {
        string dataString = string.Empty;
        var type = data.GetType();

        // Insert magic here to get values for PlayerId, PlayerName, etc...

        return dataString;
    }
```

How can we make this happen? I'm using C# 4.0.

**Updates**
The classes I'm using are generated from an edmx model, connecting to a database. This is for a reporting tool that will parse various tables and report errors to a user via email. The users have specifically requested the ability to see the contents of all fields.

Comment: That is the opposite of parsing - serializing. "Magic" can be any serializer - JSON, for example, or XML, or other tools.

Comment: The best solution depends on what kind of output you want, and what the possible types for T might be (is this a handful of your own classes, or could it be anything at all).

Comment: What will you use the output string for? Debugging? Will you save the string? Do you need to build the object again from the string? Should it be readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
        foreach(T item in data)
        {
            var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach(var prop in props)
            {   
                dataString += prop.GetValue(item, null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the list of strings. You might also be better off with using StringBuilder instead of +=.

Answer (score 5):

Every type inherits the `ToString` method from `object`. Override `ToString` in your classes.

```cs
public class Player
{
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Player [ID = {0}, Name = {1}]",
                             PlayerId, PlayerName);
    }

}
```

Then you can use the non-generic `IEnumerable` to work on them. (Why limit yourself to `List<T>` if you can have a free lunch with `IEnumerable`? The latter will work with `List<T>`, arrays, `SortedLists<T>`, `HashSet<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, algorithmic implementations of `IEnumerable` not based on a collection at all, ...)

```cs
public static string GetStringOfData(IEnumerable data)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
        
    foreach (object o in data) {
        sb.Append(o).Append("; ");
    }    
    if (sb.Length >= 2 ) {
        sb.Length -= 2;
    }    
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This works with almost any type of collection.

---

Note: Overriding `ToString` has the positive side effect that the debugger will show you this string instead of just showing the type name.

Comment: This is basically the solution I was going to suggest. Polymorphic Conditional for the win!

Comment: Actually, this is a not so good approach. Sorry. What if my name is `Kobi, ID = 3;`? (and yes, I know you can escape the string, but I can keep going...) It really depends on what the OP is after, of course. `ToString()` can work if the OP is trying to build a list for quick debugging, for example.

Comment: I do like this approach. For simplicity's sake, I didn't mention that each object I have is generated via an EDMX model. I'll have to create a metadata class for each of these tables before I can apply this method.

Comment: @Kobi: Why do you want to escape a string? That's just a matter of representation. You could display strings within quotes, for instance. You have all the freedom you want within `ToString`; it depends what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Couple options here.

You could have all of your classes implement some interface, like

```
IDataString
```

which includes a method of getting string data from the object. Then your method could just accept a List of those, and return a string:

```
public static string GetStringOfData(List<IDataString> data)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var dm in data)
        {
          sb.append(dm.InterfaceMethod());
        }

        return sb.ToString()
    }
```

You could also override ToString in all of your objects, and just accept a List of objects. The code would be similar. This is assuming you don't mind losing the normal ToString functionality.

You could do this with refelction, which I think is what you're after in the question, but are you just going to concatenate all public string fields? This is a little slower and a lot more ugly but possible for sure.

Answer (score 1):

First in each of the classes override `ToString()` method:

```
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteThing { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.PlayerId.Tostring() + " " + PlayerName + " " + FavoriteThing;
    }
}
```

Then in your method concatenate all returned strings from class instances:

```
public static string GetStringOfData<T>(List<T> data)
        {
            StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (object o in data)
            {
                dataBuilder.Append(o.ToString());
                dataBuilder.Append(" ");
            }

            return dataBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

Note that it is better to concatenate strings using `StringBuilder` because of performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

The magic you are expecting might be Reflection: determining the prooperties at runtime and getting their values for each item in the list.

The code for this is the following:

```
public static string GetStringOfData<T>(List<T> list)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Where(p => !p.GetIndexParameters().Any());

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}={1};",
                                        propertyInfo.Name,
                                        propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null));
        }
        stringBuilder.AppendLine();
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```